# Ionic3 ion-img do not show images with ng-for

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

**I am trying to show the dynamic images with loop using ion-img but it is not working.**

```
<ion-item no-lines no-padding *ngFor="let company of shortedDistanceArray">
    <div>
        <ion-img style="width: 15vh;height: 12vh;" src={{company.images}}"></ion-img>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: do not show the image

Comment: So what have you done to try and debug the problem - are you getting anything on the variables `company.images`? If you provide more detail you will get more help.

Comment: no, there is no error.

Comment: i have checked there is no error in showing in console. i also tried using lazyload then it rendered the image but it do not resize the image according the css style

Comment: It's a well known bug that ion-img doesn't load images. The other solutions provided using the img tag is not a solution if you want to lazy load. Here are some options that will work for you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lazyload-image https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-image-loader

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**i found the solution use 'img' tag instead of 'ion-img'**

```
<ion-item no-lines no-padding *ngFor="let company of shortedDistanceArray">
    <div>
        <img style="width: 15vh;height: 12vh;" src={{company.images}}" />
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Before modifying your code, Google `ion-img vs img` and make sure you know the actual differences between using `ion-img` and `img` tags.

Answer (score 5):

Here you need to use `property binding` as shown below. Always try to avoid `string interpolation`.

```
<ion-item no-lines no-padding *ngFor="let company of shortedDistanceArray">
    <div>
        <img style="width: 15vh;height: 12vh;" [src]="company.images"></img>
    </div>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: still don't rendering the image with property binding

Comment: i have checked there is no error in showing in console. i also tried using lazyload then it rendered the image but it do not resize the image according the css style

Comment: use `[ngStyle]="myStyles"` for that.