# ion-img not working properly on older version of ionic ~3.*

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I print the url before returning it, and it is ok.

Image of console output.
[image]
Image of inspected html code.
[image]

Here is the html code:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of response | slice:0:10">
    <ion-avatar slot="start">
      <ion-img src="{{ getThumbnail(item.link) }}"></ion-img>
    </ion-avatar>
    <p>{{ item.title }}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Here is the getThumbnail function:

```
  getThumbnail(link: string){
    let dotLocation = link.indexOf('.', 19);
    let res = link.substring(0, dotLocation) + 's' + link.substring(dotLocation);
    console.log(res)
    return res;
  }
```

Sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't!
**Edit**

I tried it on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-rjffn1), and the same code works fine. It appears that I am using old versions of ionic and angular on my project. Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyIonicProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^1.5.2",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "8.1.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.9",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Update**

There is an open issue [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/18734), and they say a workaround for this is to set a `min-height` of `1px`.

Comment: I replaced `ion-img` with normal `img` tag, and it works everytime. But I don't know why!

Comment: As mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359153/ionic3-ion-img-do-not-show-images-with-ng-for . I tried to use binding `[src]` instead of interpolation, and the same issue occurred.

Comment: why are you slicing in ion-item? it is going to only show the first 10 characters.

Comment: @E.Maggini That was intended to not waste bandwidth, when testing with full size images :)

Comment: I see nothing wonrg with your code and I couldn't replicate the behavior. Setting up a Stackblitz might help.

Comment: You are slicing on 0:10. You will get 10 characters. So you are getting till "j" or "m". Have you tried slicing 0:12? I guess it should work. But if you can setup stackblitz and share the link.

Comment: @Sébastien I will do that

Comment: I will create a local project with newer versions of ionic and angular, then see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: some of images extensions are mp4! is it normal?!

Comment: @DiakoAmir yes, Imgur have mp4 files as well. But although the thumbnail link says .mp4 it is actaully an image! (I think)

Comment: @E.Maggini and Wahab Shah , you don't understand what the [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) does in Angular. It slices the array.